# Save Button State if pressed

Tags: java, android

I have a toggleButton in my custom Dialog. It shows "Sound On" on default. If I press the Button it changes to "Sound Off". If i close dialog and reopen it shows "Sound On".I just want to save the pressed state. I used sharedPreferences there but it still does not work as expected. I allready read some threads about this but im still not able to fix this by myself. Could someone have a quick look and show me my mistake.

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = sharedpreferences.getString("sound", "no");

        if (name.equals("no")) {
            final ToggleButton buttonSound = (ToggleButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button3);
            buttonSound.isChecked();
        }

       final ToggleButton buttonSound = (ToggleButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        buttonSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(buttonSound.isChecked()){

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("sound", "no");
                    editor.commit();

                }else if(!buttonSound.isChecked()){

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("sound", "yes");
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use `setChecked(boolean b)` to change the checked status of the button. `isChecked` tests if button is checked or not.

Comment: try using a static variable...static  String name="on";

Comment: Jeans-Baptistes answer worked fine for me. Thanks Ben for the additional hint :)